# Can pre-trained ResNet50 be used for very low resolution image?

Tags: deep-learning, resnet, multimodal

It's required to find the best image given with a text description. However, the resolution is very low, i.e., 50 x 50 pixels.

In this case, can pre-trained ResNet50 be used? or any recommendations on a better architecture? Thanks!